# MRTK Object Manipulation : why is my 2D object not interactable?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

[EDIT] I can now see the bounding boxes but can't interact

I'm trying to add some interaction to my app. Basically I have a 2D Sprite and I want to be able to scale and rotate it using both hands.

To do that I followed the documentation about [object manipulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/ux-building-blocks/object-manipulator?view=mrtkunity-2021-05) and added the following settings :
[image]

I also added a `Box Collider 2D` to my element and the `NearInteractionGrabbable` script from MRTK.

**The problem**
However, I can't interact with my object, I don't see any bounding boxes and the audio clip isn't playing.

What am I doing wrong ?

PS: I work on Hololens 1st gen, Unity 2019.4.36f and MRTK 2.8.2.0

Comment: It seems like it comes from proximity (while using the computer webcam, my virtual object is closer than when using the Hololens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, we use 3D colliders in HoloLens for interaction. And as far as I know 3D colliders and 2D colliders cannot work together in Unity, so here you can try to add a 3D collider to the 2D sprite.

Comment: Yes I did that and with a settings you can flatten it so it becomes 2D. Now my only issue is that I can grab the corners and interact while using Unity player but not when I try the app on the Hololens. On the Hololens I can see the bounding boxe and the handles but I can't grab them (even if the pointer is on the handle)

Comment: I did some tests but didn't reproduce this issue. Which MixedRealityToolkitProfile are you using? Is it DefaultHoloLens1ConfigurationProfile? Also, it should be noted that HoloLens 1 does not support direct hand interaction, you need to interact with [Gaze and commit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/design/gaze-and-commit).

Comment: I just found a work around, basically you can define in `BoundsControl` the collider padding of the handles which I just changed to `1` and now I can easily interact with my object